Trying to understand a log entry in an iis log file
One of my rest services has gone offline on an older server (iis 7).  And while I do need to move this to an updated server; I need to get it back online at least for the short term.
I'm hitting it with postman to check the response but am getting a 500 server error in return.
Sadly, it doesn't seem FailedReqLogFiles gets updated for rest services; at least nothing is appearing there.
In the iis log file for the site I have this:
2024-05-16 13:32:41 10.1.1.101 GET /api/GetInfo  -  443  checkuser  10.1.1.202  PostManRuntime/7.37.3  500 0 0 15312
I understand most of the line except for the last 3 numbers.
500 is the error, but what is 0 0 15312?

Take a look at the header of the log file.
They are

the sub status error code
the windows status code
the length of time that the action took, in milliseconds


Thanks, I looked for a header, but didn't realize the header was about 8 lines down. I see it now, thanks for your help.
